# Working Ember.Router example

Tags: ember.js

Can somebody please share a working Ember.router example? None of the examples I saw on the internet seem to compliant to latest Ember guidelines? Most of them use App.initialize() which is deprecated? If a 'root' route is defined in a Router, will it be called automatically (or) how to initialize the router's first state? Also, 'connectOutlets' does not seem to be defined in RC 3 release? Any pointers will be of great help? I need to make my views work with routers and outlets without urls (planning to use location: none in Router definition)?

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not free but the [peepcode for Ember](https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs) includes examples for the 1.0 release candidate and it is extremely complete

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a lot of questions.

I advise you to watch this video of Yehuda Katz live coding an app with the latest Ember and giving great tips.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6RFyVN9sNg

For the the connectOutlets you have to use instead the renderTemplate function in the Route.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('index', {path: '/'});
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
        this.render('test1', {outlet: 'test1'});
        this.render('test2', {outlet: 'test2'});
        ...
    }
});
```

Hope it helps